# Counting the number of times each variable appears in table

Tags: php, mysql

Basically, I am seeking to know if there is a better way to accomplish this specific task.

Basically, what happens is I query the db for a list of "project needs" -- These are each uniquer and only appear once.

Then, I search another table to find out how many members have the required "skills - which are directly correlated to the project needs".

I accomplished exactly what I was trying to do by running a second query and then inserting them into an array like this:

```
function countEachSkill(){
    $return = array();
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT SKILL_ID, SKILL_NAME FROM PROJECT_NEEDS";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNT FROM MEMBER_SKILLS WHERE SKILL_ID = '".$row['NEED_ID']."'";
            $cResult = mysql_query($query);
            $cRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($cResult);
            $return[$row['SKILL_ID']]['Count'] = $cRow['COUNT'];
            $return[$row['SKILL_ID']]['Name'] = $row['SKILL_NAME'];
        }   
    arsort($return);

    return $return; 

}
```

But I feel like there has to be a better way (perhaps using some kind of join?) that would return this in a result set to avoid using the array.

Thanks in advance.

PS. I know mysql_ is depreciated. It is not my choice on which to use.

Comment: @EdGibbs - are you missing a join between project_needs and member_skills?

Comment: Too right I am - thanks! I didn't look closely enough at the queries. I don't have time to answer this fully so it's best if I just delete my comment. Thanks again - good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT P.SKILL_ID, P.SKILL_NAME, COUNT(M.SKILL_ID) as COUNT FROM PROJECT_NEEDS P INNER JOIN MEMBER_SKILLS M
ON P.SKILL_ID=M.SKILL_ID
GROUP BY P.SKILL_ID, P.SKILL_NAME
```

Comment: Just got back into the office -- I'll check through the answers provided and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Can you test this query

```
select project_needs.*,count(members_skills.*) as count  from project_needs 
inner join members_skills
on members_skills.skill_id=project_needs.skill_id Group by project_needs.skill_name, project_needs.skill_id
```

Comment: This does not comply with sql standards, and may or may not run on a mysql instance based on its configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted Nriddens answer to accomodate for the select distinct, Im under the belief that his adjustment would be ok given `SKILL_ID` is a primary key

```
function countEachSkill(){
$return = array();
$query = "
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS COUNT,
    PROJECT_NEEDS.SKILL_NAME,
    PROJECT_NEEDS.SKILL_ID
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        SKILL_ID, SKILL_NAME
    FROM
        PROJECT_NEEDS) AS PROJECT_NEEDS
        INNER JOIN
    MEMBER_SKILLS
ON
    MEMBER_SKILLS.SKILL_ID = PROJECT_NEEDS.SKILL_ID
GROUP BY PROJECT_NEEDS.SKILL_ID";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $return[$row['SKILL_ID']]['Count'] = $row['COUNT'];
        $return[$row['SKILL_ID']]['Name'] = $row['SKILL_NAME'];
    }   
arsort($return);

return $return;
```

I am subquerying on the select distinct because I dont believe you have a dedicated skills table with an auto inc primary key,  if that was there I wouldn't be using a subquery.

Comment: This seems slightly overcomplicated

Comment: Just got back into the office -- I'll check through the answers provided and report back.

Comment: Ive altered it slightly, the row variable was missing

Comment: And i missed a group by as well.

Comment: I tested the answer above first and it works exactly as I expected. I appreciate the time you put forth to answer my question

Comment: Do you have duplicate skill Ids in the project needs table?

Comment: In the PN table no, in the MS table yes. The Project Needs table acts as the look-up table for the Member Skills table as the MS table only holds the Need Id -- the Need ID is the primary key in the project_needs table